# Integrate WSO2 Api Manager with Certificate manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, aws-certificate-manager

I want to integrate WSO2 APi manager with a certificate manager to create alerts for certificates that are about to revoke. And the software should be open source for professionals, so thats why I dont choose WSo2 Identity Server.

I have seen that maybe Cert Manager integrated with Lets Encrypt can do this, but the tutorials are inexistent. Is there any other solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU You can't directly integrate WSO2 APIM with a certificate manager. But all the certs that are used by WSO2 are in `client-truststore.jks` and `wso2carbon.jks` located at `<AM_HOME>/repository/resources/security`. So you can monitor the certs in these stores and generate alerts.